# MySQL многотабличный запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Мне необходимо создать многотабличный запрос, который определяет, какая книга была взята больше всего раз в каждой возрастной категории. Я написал запрос, который создает таблицу из необходимых нам полей и подсчитывает, сколько раз брали каждую книгу. Каким образом можно дополнить его так, чтобы он сначала делал выборку по возрастным категориям, а после -выбирал бы самую востребованную книгу? Стоит отметить, что моя проблема заключается в том, что я не могу понять, как работать с таблицей, собранной из нескольких разных, ведь у нее нет конкретного имени.

```sql
SELECT  Orders.book_name,
case 
when TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,Date_of_Birth,curdate()) 
    between 5 and 10
    then '5-10'
when TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,Date_of_Birth,curdate()) 
    between 11 and 15
    then '11-15'
when TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,Date_of_Birth,curdate()) 
    between 16 and 20
    then '16-20'  
when TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,Date_of_Birth,curdate()) 
    between 21 and 30
    then '21-30'  
when TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,Date_of_Birth,curdate()) 
    between 31 and 40
    then '31-40'  
when TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,Date_of_Birth,curdate()) 
    between 41 and 120
    then '41-120' 
else null end as Age_group,
COUNT(Orders.Book_name) AS How_often
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.idcustomer=Orders.idCustomer  
GROUP BY Book_name
ORDER BY Age_group;
```

Comment: Что-то я не понял вопроса, вы хотите сохранить данный запрос в таблицу что-ли?

Comment: Вам нужно выбрать самую востребованную книгу в каждой категории? Чтобы работать с запросом, как с таблицей - Вы можете обернуть его еще в один `select` типа: `select q.* from ( ваш запрос ) q` [документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html), [простой пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/24587)

Answer (score 1):

> моя проблема заключается в том, что я не могу понять, как работать с
>   таблицей, собранной из нескольких разных, ведь у нее нет конкретного
>   имени.

Вам нужно понять, что результат запроса, это НЕ таблица, а набор БД записей, выведенные в табличной форме. В табличной форме лишь для Вашего удобства, как пользователя. Эти записи где-то там на сервере временно хранятся, пока выполняется Ваш запрос. Как только выполнится и выдастся Вам на экран (или куда надо), сервер их сотрет из памяти.

Ну и в качестве ответа на Ваш вопрос: эта "таблица" (AKA набор записей) может быть использована также, как и реальные таблицы БД.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM table2 t2 
    JOIN table t3 ON t2.[fld]=t3.[fld] 
    WHERE [whatever] 
    GROUP BY [whatever]) tempT2 ON t1.[fld]=tempT2.[fld]
WHERE [whatever]
```

Я объясню:

- `table1`, `table2` и `table` - реальные таблицы в БД
- все, что в скобках - это как раз и есть результат запроса. Это как раз и есть та самая "таблица, у которой нет конкретного имени"
- `tempT2` - это мы присваиваем имя этой таблице-без-имени, и теперь она именуется `tempT2`. Однако надо понимать, что физически ее не существует. Она есть только пока выполняется запрос.
- поскольку у "таблицы" теперь есть имя, к ней теперь можно обращаться как к обычной... `JOIN`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` - как обычно

Однако надо учитывать следующие моменты:

- такого типа конструкции `JOIN (SELECT ...)` не сильно приветствуются. В зависимости от размеров таблиц-источников, это может жрать много ресурсов. Старайтесь все-таки максимально делать внутри запроса.
- при работе с под-запросами есть некоторые ограничения. Особенно при группировке данных - MySQL Вам сообщит

Надеюсь, теперь понятнее станет :)

Answer (score 0):

> Каким образом можно дополнить его так, чтобы он сначала делал выборку по возрастным категориям, а после -выбирал бы самую востребованную книгу?

во-первых, вам надо группировать записи по возрастным группам, т.е. директива `group by` должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
group by age_group
```

во-вторых, сортируйте так, как вам надо — если сначала должна произойти сортировка по возрастным группам, а затем по количеству записей, то директива `order by` должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
order by age_group, how_often
```